# Minimal number of edges in graph such that every triple has a connected pair

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If we have a graph with 6 vertices, what is the minimal amount of edges needed, $k_6$, and how should they be put in the graph, in such manner that if I choose any 3 vertices of the graph at least two of them are certainly connected by an edge?

My guess is that 6 edges are needed forming two disconected triangles, but I am not sure how to prove that this is the minimal number. This is clearly the minimal number if the graph has two disconnected components, but how can I be sure that it is impossible to do with a smallest number of edges if the graph is connected?

And while we are at it, how could one attack the problem with $n$ vertices? that is how to find $k_n$? clearly $k_3 =1, k_4=2$

Comment: You are correct, you need at least $6$ edges, and the only graph with six vertices is the one that you proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph with the least edges that does not have an independent set of $r+1$ vertices is always the complement of the [Turan graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n_graph#Tur.C3.A1n.27s_theorem) $T(n,r)$ and it is in fact the only graph with that number of edges satisfying that property.

It should be clear that a graph $G$ without $r$ independent vertices satisfies that it's complement contains no $K_r$ as a subgraph and vice-versa. So you need to find the graph on $n$ vertices with the most number of edges that does not have a $K_r$ and take it's complement, but by [Turan's theorem](https://www.google.com.mx/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Turan+theorem&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=mHMHVfORLo3J8gfjzYFQ) that graph is the Turan graph. So what we want is the complement of the Turan graph.

The complement of the Turan graph $T(n,r+1)$  is in general a the graph on $n$ vertices that has $r$ components, where each component is complete and where the differences between the sizes of components is at most one. So in your case the graph is composed of two $K_3$'s, in other words two disjoint triangles.